# Recommended websites and literature for new programmers

Tags: programming-languages, logic

We are creating an open-source group  with a large emphasis on introducing designers to programming. I have a library of material that I believe is important but I want the opinion of Stack. What do you guys believe is a good path for the casual programmer to start out on?
 
Since this is an open group and we do not really know who is going to show up we want to cover the bases. Although we are prepared for the worst we expect that any one attending will have graduated high-school and will have an understanding of the necessary algebra.(cringe)
I am looking for the best links to any online materials that people have found useful for teaching introduction to programming and logic.

We hope to amass enough material to compile a simple wiki that can serve as the basses for our lesson plan.

http://www.imaginaryphysics.org/opensource.html

Thank you for any help and opinions you can offer.

Comment: You are basically trying to condense 3 years worth of university courses into a Wiki...? :)

Comment: It really depends on the programming langage. Each langage has it own best ressources. I'm not aware of some good links/books that will teach you how to make good programs with any langages.

Give us so more advices about the coding langage your users will want to learn to use.

Comment: This cannot really be answered, i don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a few :

- http://apache.org/
- http://sourcemaking.com/
- http://www.infoq.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) of course!

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about Open Source... do you have a platform in mind? I mean, if you are looking for free, try a LAMP approach... I guess. I agree with everyone in the comments that this is pretty open-ended, and I would have left this as a comment as it really isn't an answer, but it is getting kinda long with the link. Below is the w3c tutorial.
[PHP Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)

Most school however start with C++, to put it overly simple (please don't flame me for that, I'm trying to simplify): it is kinda the base of most programming languages.
[C++ Tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/)

It should be noted, though, that training programmers doesn't only take knowing a language. It takes reordering the way you think. That is why getting a computer science degree takes 4 years and you need to study advanced mathematics, logic, science, etc. Being a programmer is a life long learning process, true, but it does take a base knowledge to get started. If you are trying to help the youth, more power to you! But, you should probably know what you are getting into :)